# Harddrive Compatibility Issues

Tags: hard-drive

i recently bought a HP DL580 G7 from ebay. It didnt come with harddrives so i bought 2 x ST1200MM0118 harddrives.

I am seeing hell to try to get it working. I contacted HP support who told me to purchase HP harddrives ( not very helpful ), however they did assist me in updating the firmware of the p410i controller to 6.64 and all over drives using the SPP to the newest for that server.

I still get no response from both drives. Ive tried what i believe to be EVERYTHING. Ive tried booting with only 1 drive in, ive tried a random sata drive i have laying around ( which works perfectly in my external sata to usb dock ).

Im wondering if the backplane or the sas cable could be the problem, however im wondering if that might even be the problem.

When i log into the iLO, the 2 harddrive informations says "fault" which leads me to believe the problem may be with the drives and not the sas cables or the backplane.

Im looking for some suggestions on what would be the best way forward.

[image: Screenshot on Boot]

Comment: Whilst this won't be helpful with your problem but you're going to run into the same problem as I did where HP has, on purpose, crippled their RAID adapters so that if you use 3rd party (read: non HP branded drives) the fans will go into overdrive and blow at 100% so if you're going to  run this server in a non-server room environment, be prepared to be in a world of hurt.

Edit:
What did pop into my mind was, did you completely erase and RAID information that may have been left over from the previous owner from the option rom config for arrays? F8 on startup as I recall.

Comment: Ok so i defaulted the entire server erasing memory or all raid etc. The machine rebooted and even rechecked all the memory etc. so i believe the server is at its full default state. Same issue with the hard drives. I am even beginning to even wonder if my harddrives are even good, but i dont see 2 used drives both being bad at the same time. so leads me back to wonder if it might be the sas or backplane... im trying to avoid wasting money on purchasing another back plane and sas cables and cant confirm if they are the problem.

Comment: Could you please add to your question a picture of your server booting at a point when RAID adapter initialized, displayed the detected drives and waits for F8 to be clicked...

Comment: Im not sure how to upload am image yet, but i can tell you what it says.

Slot 0 HP Smart Array P410i Controller (1024MB, v6.64) 0 Logical Drives
1785-Slot 0 Drive Array Not Configured
         No Drives Detected

Press <F8> to run the Option ROM Configuration for Arrays Utility
Press <F6> to run the Option ROM Configuration Command Line Interface
Press <ESC> to Skip Configuration and Continue

Comment: I Uploaded a screenshot to the original quesiton

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so solution was to purchase a LSI card. The HP server backplane and even the SAS cables worked, everything works perfectly now